# Store methods in an array and call them in C#

Tags: c#, .net, function

In javascript we can do this:

```
var arr = [];

function fooBar() {
    console.log('Hello World');
}

arr[0] = fooBar;

arr[0]();
```

Essentially each function is a real object and I can store them in an array if I want to. My question is, since C# doesnt have pointers, what is the best way to handle such as scenario? I mean how can I store function references into arrays?

I know we have something called delegates but im not sure if this is the right thing for the task...

Comment: Store them in a [`System.Delegate[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's what delegates and lambdas are for. These *are* function pointers done right.

Comment: What .net version?

Comment: `var myCalls=new{ ()=>fooBar()};`

Comment: `var foobar=new Action[] {foo,bar};` Also works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Delegates are *exactly* what you need:

```
var list = new List<Action>();
```

...

```
void fooBar() {
    ....
}
```

...

```
list.Add(fooBar);
```

The [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) is actually nothing but a `delegate`, simply look its definiton and you´ll see it is similar to a delegate expecting nothing and returning nothing. If you want to pass parameters use any of it´s generic versions, for example `Action<T>`. If you also need to add methods that return something use the [`Func`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx)-delegate instead.

EDIT: Every delegate has its own type so you can´t mix them and put them alltogether into one single collection, except you use a collection of type `Delegate`:

```
var list = new List<Delegate>();
```

In this case you can´t use urual braces to *call* the actual delegate, instead you have to use `DynamicInvoke` and pass the arguments according to the delegates signature.

```
list[0].DynamicInvoke(args);
```

Comment: So its nearly as similar. I thought we need the delegate keyword or something

Comment: Even more similar `var foobar=new Action[] {foo,bar};` or `var foobar=new List<Action> {foo,bar};` . The compiler realizes that these are delegates to the methods.

Comment: Can it be done with a dictionary too? Such as Dictionary<string, Func>()

Comment: @Asperger Sure, try it out

Comment: Are you looking for `dynamic` or `ExpandoObject` after all? You can add properties or methods to an expando object and call them by name. Internally, they *are* stored as dictionaries

Comment: This is a VERY good answer. I will wait a bit more just in case.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your comments. They were also very useful!

Answer (score 8):

Delegates are the right thing for the task - they're equivalent to a strongly-typed function pointer.

Because each delegate is its own type you cannot mix-and-match different delegate types in an array type to a single delegate-type, you can use the parent `System.Delegate` to allow you to store delegates of different types in the array, though you lose the ability to invoke them directly without some side-channel that informs your program of their arguments.

For example:

```
public static String Meow(Cat cat) { return "meow"; }
public static String Purr(Cat cat) { return "purr"; }

delegate String CatSound(Cat cat);

CatSound[] catSounds = new CatSound[] {
    Meow,
    Purr
};
```

You can then invoke them directly:

```
Cat orion = new Cat();
catSounds[0]( orion ); // meow
catSounds[1]( orion ); // purr
```

If you want to add a `DogSound` delegate to your collection, you'll have a harder job: you need to use `Delegate[]` instead...

```
delegate String DogSound(Dog dog);

Delegate[] petSounds = new Delegate[] {
    new CatSound( Meow ),
    new CatSound( Purr ),
    new DogSound( Woof ),
    new DogSound( Bark ),
}; // note that C# compiler allows shorthand syntax where simply `Meow` is behind-the-scenes converted into `new CatSound( Meow )`.
```

...and you have to invoke it using the `DynamicInvoke` method ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke(v=vs.110).aspx ) which means you'll lose compile-time verification of correct arguments, instead any call made with incorrect arguments will fail at runtime with a `MemberAccessException`.

```
Dog pupper = new Dog();
Cat orion = new Cat();

petSounds[0].DynamicInvoke( orion );
petSounds[1].DynamicInvoke( orion );
petSounds[2].DynamicInvoke( pupper ); // ok, this is a DogSound
petSounds[3].DynamicInvoke( orion ); // this will fail at runtime because you're passing a Cat into a DogSound delegate
```

You can also think of delgates as "an `interface` for a single method".

Prior to the .NET Framework 3.5, you generally needed to define your own delegate types using the `delegate` keyword (note that the `delegate` keyword is also overloaded for anonymous functions in C# 3.0), however there is now `System.Action` and `System.Func` which serve 95% of cases where you would have previously needed to define your own type. Indeed, today my `delegate CatSound` is unnecessary, you could just use `Func<Cat,String>` instead.

Comment: use this if your .net version does not support Action or Func

Answer (score 3):

Given that the functions to call have the same signature, it could be done by using the predefined [generics for delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows.

```
Func<int,int> Square = x => x*x;
Func<int,int> Successor = x => x+1;
Func<int,int> Functions[] = new Func<int,int>[]{ Square, Successor };

int A = Functions[0](2); // A gets assigned 4;
int B = Functions[1](1); // B gets assigned 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could Store Action or Func objects, someting like:

```
void Main()
{
    var arr = new object[2];
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = (Action)DoIt;

    foreach (var a in arr)
    {
        if (a is Action)
        {
            ((Action)a)();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        }
    }
}


public void DoIt()
{
    Console.WriteLine("did");       
}
```

Comment: Are Func and Action equivalent?

Comment: no action has no return set, function does. see my answer for the msdn documentation

Answer (score 2):

Consider actions (depending on .net verion)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx

```
List<Action<string>> actions = new List<Action<string>>();

    actions.Add(() => {
      //do stuff
    });
```

or if you need rturn values use Func: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

yea through delegates you can:

```
static void iammain()
{
  List<Action> lst = new List<Action>();
  lst.AddRange(new Action[] { proc1, proc2, proc3 });
  for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
  {
    lst[i]();

  }

}
static void proc1()
{
  Console.WriteLine("i am proc1");

}
static void proc2()
{
  Console.WriteLine("i am proc2");

}
static void proc3()
{
  Console.WriteLine("i am proc3");

}
```